# Two way voice transmission using Arduino or Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino

Can voice transmission be done by Arduino or Raspberry Pi?

I am trying to make a baby monitoring device. So I need to know can I transmit voice with Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You need to show what your research has shown you. When you get stuck then ask a specific, answerable question related to electronic design. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help for how this site works.

Comment: In all honesty, if you are trying to make a baby monitor for a baby that has already been born, *buy a baby monitor*.  You may think you are going to save $50 or something via DIY, but it probably won't be that much by the time you are done and based on the degree of experience implied in your question, it is going to be very seriously disproportionate to the amount of time it will take you to implement -- not to mention the fact that by then it may count as a "toddler monitor".  I am not trying to be rude.  I am trying to spare you a mistake and prolonged headache.

Comment: However, if this is a no pressure project where a major part of the goal is to learn by doing, then yes it can be done with a pi -- but you will need to get at minimum a USB audio adapter w/ a mic jack, because Pi's do not have audio *inputs* of their own.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Uno, probably not. A weak microcontroller with no ADC or DAC audio capabilities, plus no radios or network capabilities built in.

RPi, sure. It's a full blown computer. Usb for audio in, built in audio out, built in Ethernet or wifi via usb for transmission. You will need to find a Linux based solution for intercom/audio transmission if you want to use the RPi, a mostly software setup.

Or go with a pair of [ESP boards and upgrade a baby monitor.](http://hackaday.com/2016/07/15/baby-monitor-rebuild-is-also-esp8266-audio-streaming-how-to/)

Comment: Why linux? I'd imagine you'd have a hard time finding a commercial Linux based baby monitor

Comment: There are plenty of Linux-based audio streaming solutions.

Comment: ... and many more non Linux-based systems.  I suppose I'm moaning about the term "need"

Comment: @ScottSeidman sure you could just go whole hog analog. But considering op thought of an Arduino and rpi, I doubt they will be willing or easily capable of doing a rf setup. Linux or an IP solution is simple too. But the "need" is in reference of how to do it on the RPi

Comment: Arduino is not weak just because its not an ARM or x86 :D It is very simple to wire up a microphone and broadcast it via FM from Arduino (something the Pi cannot do) But the Pi can receive FM using GPIO hacks.